# Non-focusable child window

Tags: delphi, dll-injection

I have simple VCL form, this form located in injected dll. Dll injected to process with window. I need to make my form to be non-focusable and always before parent window (main window of the injected process).

Form creation:

```
procedure CreateForm;
var
  hWindow: THandle;
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  if GetProcessWindowHandle(GetCurrentProcessId, hWindow) then begin
    FormButtons := TFormButtons.Create(nil);
    GetWindowRect(hWindow, Rect);
    FormButtons.Left := Rect.Left + 50;
    FormButtons.Top  := Rect.Top;
    FormButtons.ShowModal;
    FormButtons.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure DLLEntryPoint(dwReason: DWORD);
begin
  case dwReason of
    DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: begin
                          CreateForm;
                        end;
    DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: begin
                        end;
  end;
end;

begin
  DLLProc := @DLLEntryPoint;
  DLLEntryPoint(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

CreateParams for form:

```
procedure TFormButtons.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
var
  hWindow: THandle;
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
  if GetProcessWindowHandle(GetCurrentProcessId, hWindow) then
    Params.WndParent := hWindow;
end;
```

What I have:

1. With `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` and without `Params.WndParent := hWindow` I have non-focusable my window (TFormButtons), but this is not child window for main window and when main window activated than my window stay under main window. Stay on top is a bad idea, my window should be only before main window.
2. With `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` and wit `Params.WndParent := hWindow` I have good z-ordering for my child VCL window, this is always before main window, but main window always lost focus when activated my window
3. And another question: how to show my VCL window without `ShowModal` but with `Show`. Without `ShowModal` this is invisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution. My form never got focus, placed every time over main form and moved with main form:

Injected dll:

```
var
  hWndHook: HHOOK = 0;
  hWndMain: THandle = 0;
  ProcessId: DWORD = 0;
  ThreadId: DWORD = 0;

function CallWndProc(Code: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; CWPStruct: PCWPStruct): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(hWndHook, Code, wParam, LPARAM(CWPStruct));
  if (Code = HC_ACTION) then begin
    case CWPStruct.message of
      WM_MOVE: if hWndMain > 0 then begin
        if Assigned(FormButtons) then begin
          GetWindowRect(hWndMain, Rect);
          SetWindowPos(FormButtons.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, Rect.Left, Rect.Top - 10, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOSIZE);
          SetWindowPos(FormButtons.Handle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE);
        end;
      end;
      WM_ACTIVATE: if (hWndMain > 0) then begin
        if Assigned(FormButtons) then begin
          SetWindowPos(FormButtons.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE);
          SetWindowPos(FormButtons.Handle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE);
        end;
      end;
      WM_CLOSE: if (hWndMain > 0) and (hWndMain = CWPStruct.hwnd) then begin
        try
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hWndHook);
            hWndMain := 0;
        except
          MessageBox(0, 'Error: WM_CLOSE', '', MB_OK);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function ThreadProc(Params: Pointer): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  try
    ProcessId := GetCurrentProcessId;
    if GetProcessWindowHandle(ProcessId, hWndMain) then
      ThreadId := GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWndMain);

    if hWndHook = 0 then
      hWndHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, @CallWndProc, HInstance, ThreadId);
//    MessageBox(0, PChar('Hook installed!' + sLineBreak +
//                        'Process Id: ' + IntToStr(ProcessId) + sLineBreak +
//                        'Thread Id: ' + IntToStr(ThreadId) + sLineBreak +
//                        'hWndMain: ' + IntToStr(hWndMain) + sLineBreak +
//                        'hWndHook: ' + IntToStr(hWndHook)), '', MB_OK);

    FormButtons := TFormButtons.Create(nil);
    FormButtons.ShowModal;

    Result := 0;
  except
//    Result := ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
  end;
end;

procedure DLLEntryPoint(dwReason: DWORD);
var
  hThread: THandle;
  ThreadId: UInt32;
begin
  case dwReason of
    DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: begin
//                          MessageBox(0, PChar('DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: ' + IntToStr(ProcessId)), '', MB_OK);
                        end;
    DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: begin
                          hThread := BeginThread(nil, 0, ThreadProc, nil, 0, ThreadId);
                          if hThread <> 0 then
                            CloseHandle(hThread);
//                          MessageBox(0, PChar('DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: ' + IntToStr(GetCurrentProcessId)), '', MB_OK);
                        end;
  end;
end;

begin
  DLLProc := @DLLEntryPoint;
  DLLEntryPoint(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

CreateParams for form:

```
procedure TFormButtons.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
var
  hWindow: THandle;
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably with a class helper handling **WM_NCHITTEST** message of the form.

```
procedure TFormButtonsHelper.WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
    if (Msg.Result <> HTHSCROLL) and (Msg.Result <> HTVSCROLL) then
        Msg.Result := HTCLIENT;
end;
```

Comment: This can't help. Form received focus even after click on the client area